# Getting Status code as 406 and content-Type of response header is text/html instead of application/json

Tags: ajax, json, spring, http-status-code-406

Getting Status code as 406 `"The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."`

While upgrading spring version(`3.1.2` to `3.2.13`) I am getting 406 error from server.

```
Content-Type of Response headers:"Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8". 
Request Header is Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01. 
JavaCode:"@RequestMapping(value = "/search",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")".
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({    
            url : /search.htm,
            dataType : json,
            data : postData,
            contentType: application/json,
            .
            .
            .});
```

- Spring 3.2.13
- jackson-annotations-2.1.2
- jackson-core-2.1.2
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.9
- jackson-databind-2.1.2
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9

But while using following configurations, its working perfectly.(Here `Content-Type` of Response headers:`application/json`)

- Spring 3.1.2
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.9
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: First you need to check your rest API code. What content/type it is expecting and producing.

Comment: @ManojP it produces appilcation /json and same code is working when we have spring 3.1.2 and jackson-core-asl-1.9.9 and jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9

Comment: Found the issue.Its because of "url : /search.htm" in ajax call. We need to remove ".htm". After implementing annotations, still seraching /search.htm in spring.xml. so to avoid this we should modify spring xml without .htm. Wondering this did not happen previous versions of Spring.